# Hyperform addClass upon validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, safari, mobile-safari

I want to activate a loader class upon form validation using [Hyperform](https://hyperform.js.org/).

It is not working.

When the user presses the `create` button:

- The form should be validated.
- If the form is valid it executes the loader by adding the `is-active` class that I've made.

I am using [Hyperform](https://hyperform.js.org/) because I need to validate the form on mobile Safari.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="loader" class="loader loader-default" data-text="In Process"></div>
<button id="send" name="send" class="btn btn-create">create</button>

<script>
$("#send").click(function(){
   $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
      console.log( "Succesful Request!" );
        $("#loader").addClass("is-active");
    }});
</script>
```

After validation with [Hyperform](https://hyperform.js.org/):

```
//Script
<script>
  input.addEventListener('valid', event => {
    var d = document.getElementById("loader");
    d.className ="loader loader-default";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add what goes wrong with your attempt? Why does it not work?

Comment: Nvmnd, used a custom javascript validation function instead. Thanks anyways